# Method 'onDraw()' will be called twice when 'invalidate' is called

Tags: android, ondraw, invalidation

Method '**onDraw()**' will be called twice when '**`invalidate`**' is called.
I want to move the view up in `onDraw()`,here is my code

```
package com.blsm.sss.view;

public class MoveRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private int mDelta = 0;

    public MoveRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MoveRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void move(int delta) {

        mDelta = delta;     
        invalidate();       
        Logger.d("MoveRelativeLayout", "move() delta:" + mDelta);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Logger.d("MoveRelativeLayout", "onDraw() delta:" + mDelta);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, mDelta);
    }
}
```

But when i call the method '`move()`' `onDraw` will be called twice. I don't know why , can anyone help me?

Comment: If you don't call invalidate(), whether the onDraw() will be called?

Answer (score 0):

Is it likely that the move() method will be called from a thread other than the UI Thread? If so, I would start by using postInvalidate() and see if you get the same problem...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to call super.onDraw();